# Returning http status code 409 Conflict (without ASP.NET MVC alterations)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to return a HTTP response with 409 status code, content type "application/json" and a json data in the content.

The problem is that at the client level, response.content returns html result. Somehow ASP.Net MVC has decided to return a html error message instead of what I intended. I've checked at web.config and 409 is not part of the custom error message. I've checked IIS 7.0 Error Pages section as well for 409 and it is not set there.

I wonder where I can find the default configuration that manage asp.net mvc http error code mechanism.

I am working based on ASP.Net MVC 2.0 and .Net 4.0 on Vista.

Comment: (For anyone similarly confused as me: the code is "409 Conflict" http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.10 - I initially parsed it as "409 Result Unmolested")

Answer (score 2):

Try doing  Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true; when sending the response back which will allow to skip the IIS Customer errors. You can read more about it in
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Apr/29/IIS-7-Error-Pages-taking-over-500-Errors