# jsonResult not returned by OnActionExecuting event

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created an ActionFilterAttribute that validates an account is available for processing before allowing the MVC controller get/post request to be processed.  If the account is not available I want to return an error to the client.  If the request is an ajax post I want to include json data in the response.  For some reason the json data is only returned to the browser when the browser and website are running on the same machine.  If I browse the website on another machine and preform the ajax post the response Content-Type is returned as "text/html".  But if the browser is running on the same machine as the web site the response Content-Type is properly returned as "application/json".

What am I doing wrong?

ActionFilterAttribute

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

    if (filterContext.Result == null)
    {
        if (IsAccountUnavailable(Key))
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict;
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
                {
                    Data = new {Error = "Unavailable", Url = GetLogOffUrl()},
                    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                };
            }
          else
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(GetLogOffUrl());
        }
    }
}
```

jQuery ajax post

```
$.ajax({
    url: window.location.href,
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(ko.mapping.toJS(serverModel.SelectionsViewModel)),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json'
})
    .done(function (data) {
        if (data.isValid)
            window.location.href = serverModel.NextView();
        else
            showGenericSaveError();
    })
    .fail(function (jqXhr) {
        handleAjaxError(jqXhr);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to a co-worker who found the following post my issue has been resolved.  I needed to set Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true

[Returning http status code 409 Conflict (without ASP.NET MVC alterations)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604696/returning-http-status-code-409-conflict-without-asp-net-mvc-alterations)

Working code...

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

    if (filterContext.Result == null)
    {
        if (QuoteServiceLayer.IsAccountUnavailable(AccountKey, EnrollmentPeriodType, EmployeeKey))
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict;
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
                {
                    Data = new {Error = "Unavailable", Url = GetLogOffUrl()},
                    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                };
            }
        else
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(GetLogOffUrl());
        }
    }
}
```